# Problem with not() selector in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm having problems with the following line of jQuery code

```
 var controls = selectedForm.find('input:not(type="hidden"), checkbox, select, textarea');
```

What I'm trying to do is to select all the elements in selectedForm that are not `<input type='hidden'....>`.  selectedForm is a previous selector that selects the form object of interest.  There a total of 5 fields inside this form, one of which is the hidden input field.

My problem is that in IE8, the variable "control" contains all 5 fields inside the form.  In FF6, this works correctly and returns the 4 fields I'm interested in.

I'm assuming that I have a syntax error, but I cannot see what it is.

Comment: Everything inside the `:not()` statement still needs to be used appropriately as it would appear outside the `:not()` statement, e.g. `:not([attribute="value"])` or `:not(:last-child)`. I'm extremely surprised that the statement works in FireFox, as it should not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note you are trying to use an [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for the attribute "type" which should be enclosed with brackets:

```
var controls = selectedForm.find('input:not([type="hidden"]), checkbox, select, textarea');
```

Answer (score 1):

John Hartsock correctly identified the problem there (must use `[type="hidden"]`), however you can also write that query without using the `:not` selector:

```
selectedForm.find('input[type!="hidden"], checkbox, etc');
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Comment: On problem, it doesn't appear to work in FF6.  In IE8, works fine.